# Array address not visible

Tags: c++

Refer the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

class Boy {
    char name[10];
    public:
        void show() {
            *name = 0;
            std::cout << "\n" << &name[0];
        }
};

int main() {
    Boy b;
    b.show();

}
```

Here, why don't we see the address of name[0]. I also tried with `name`, which itself is address. Still I can't see the address, it returns blank screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're using `char*` overload for `operator<<`, which treats the pointer as a pointer to c-string. Cast your pointer to `void*` to print it as such.

```
std::cout << "\n" << static_cast<void*>(&name[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am a beginner I cant understand!

Comment: I added fixed code

Comment: That's ok. Continue to read your C++ book, and you should understand it before long.

Comment: @Sam But actually why does it not show the address, even if it treats it like pointer to c string. It should show the address?

Comment: No, it attempts to print the string. But since c-strings are zero-ended and you put zero as the first character it outputs an empty string.

Comment: Because that's how C++ works: `operator<<` on a `char *` prints the character string referenced by the pointer. And your character string is empty. It's the same reason the sky is blue, and water is wet.

Comment: Ah now I got it! Thanks!